# MS MapCruncher - Silverlight Bing Maps

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps

Is there a version of MapCruncher that works with Silverlight Bing Maps?  Not the Ajax version.

I want to overlay PDFs (floor plans) onto a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard version of MapCruncher and Bing Maps Silverlight will do it. A quick Google gets lots of hits, for example, here's one of the more useful (also follow the link to Chris Pietschmann's article):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/8f1d38e6-12a4-4f3e-88e9-074206806cc0

The output from MapCruncher is actually very useful - I've even been able to use it Google Maps v3.